# How to convert map of map of interface to string

Tags: go

I am newer to go lang and I have a type of variable like below:

```
type ResultData map[string]map[string][]interface{}
```

When I receive data in this variable, how do I convert the whole data into single string in Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like `Sprintf`:

```
func main() {
    d1 := map[string][]interface{}{
        "a": []interface{}{20, "hello"},
        "b": []interface{}{100}}
    d2 := map[string][]interface{}{
        "x": []interface{}{"str", 10, 20},
    }

    m := make(map[string]map[string][]interface{})
    m["d1"] = d1
    m["d2"] = d2

    s := fmt.Sprintf("%v", m)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Or you could also do that with the `json` module to convert to a JSON string with `json.Marshal`. If the actual runtime type behind your `interface{}` is marshal-able to JSON, `json.Marshal` will figure it out on its own.

```
b, _ := json.Marshal(m)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```